# Data Binding Value not updating from other thread

Tags: wpf, data-binding, .net-4.5

I have a WPF Application where I have the following StepCount Property in my ViewModel, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and then I have it bound to a TextBox in my View.

```cs
public int StepCount
{
   get { return _stepCount; } 
   set
   {
      _stepCount = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("StepCount");
   }
}
```

In the XAML, here is what the DataBinding looks like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=StepCount}" />
```

This works great, and if I change the StepCount value, the Textbox value updates accordingly.

However, my issue is that I have another thread that is incrementing the StepCount, and in that case, the TextBox value is not updating.  As soon as the thread ends, the Textbox value updates to the correct value.

I need the Textbox value to update everytime my other thread increments the StepCount.  As it is right now, the Textbox value only shows an update after the thread finishes.

**The other thread is incrementing StepCount, but the change is not being displayed in the UI until the thread ends.**

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I appreciate all of the responses. This issue was puzzling because code that was previously working seemed to quit working, as was the case with these particular bindings.

When I installed VS 2011 Beta, it installs the .NET 4.5 Beta Framework, and when I uninstalled VS 2011 Beta under the suspicion that it may be causing problems, it did not uninstall the .NET 4.5 Beta Framework.

I just now uninstalled the .NET 4.5 framework and did a repair install of the .NET 4.0 framework. After completing those steps, my data bindings worked correctly, and now Textbox is correctly updating whenever another thread increments StepCount.

**So, it appears, the .NET 4.5 Beta Framework may cause issues with data bindings.**

I'll follow up with this by submitting an issue with Microsoft.

Thanks everyone for your responses.

Comment: Can you show some more code? AFAIK, this *should* work. What's your code for changing the StepCount look like? What does your OnPropertyChanged method look like?

Comment: Have 't tried it myself, but could you make it a dependencyproperty? Might have something to do with the PropertyChanged event being on the other thread. Otherwise invoking with the ui dispatcher if that's an option.

Comment: I just had another person try it out on their computer, and it worked fine.  The only difference I can think of is that I installed VS 2011 Beta, and some of my data bindings broke.

I uninstalled VS 2011 beta, but it didn't fix the issues, so there are probably some files there weren't removed or overwritten.  I'll see what I can find out and post back.

Comment: Would have been nice if you told us sooner that it worked before. Keeps us from mentioning the obvious things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've discovered the WPF classes that you've bound your View to in the View model operate within the UI thread.

Ideally you should change the StepCount property of your view model using the WPF Dispatcher and the Invoke command. This will marshell the call appropriately.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) for more information on this process.

Comment: In WPF data binding works cross-thread. You do not have to fire `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` using the dispatcher. The dispatcher is only required if you directly want to manipulate the control from another thread.

Comment: Can you please update the link to the article referenced?

Answer (score 0):

Tested just now, and all it works ok

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SimpleClass simpleClass = new SimpleClass(10);
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = simpleClass;
    }

    void IncrementViewModelProperty()
    {            
        simpleClass.StepCount += 11;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //works the same
        //Thread thread = new Thread(() => IncrementViewModelProperty());
        //thread.Start();
        Action act = IncrementViewModelProperty;
        act.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
}

public class SimpleClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SimpleClass(int stepCnt)
    {
        StepCount = stepCnt;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public int StepCount
    {
        get { return _stepCount; }
        set
        {
            _stepCount = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("StepCount");
        }
    }
    private int _stepCount;
}
```

then in xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StepCount, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Button Content="Increment value in separate thread" Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

BUT! if you will click the button fast and often, you exhausted thread pool and it is really would not update the property as expected.